# javascript to enter a password asked by another program

Tags: javascript, linux, input, console

I am creating a javascript that runs a program for installing some packages in multiple nodes, one after the other. But every node is asking for a password, so I have to input the same password 8 times, and I want the javascript to put that password for me. 
The problem is that when the installing program is asking for the password it waits for the user to enter it, and stops the javascript. Is there any solution?

Comment: If it is using a prompt, you need to rewrite the JS on a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yours is linux based system. If so run the scripts as .sh file. So that very first time to run the sh you will give password . So all other installation will be handled with this.